# access a com port from javascript or jquery in the client browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the need to access a com port in order to turn on and off a USB relay.
Now that google apps is going away, is there any other way of doing this or should I just write a desktop app?

I have complete control and access to the client PC, it does not need to work from random machines on the internet -- just in the customers warehouses.

I don't care what browser is used, needs to be windows 10 however.

Most of the answers are old...I am hoping that things have changed.

Thank you --

Joe

Comment: a web browser does not have any access to the user's PC in this way. Doesn't matter if it's "your" PC or not, the browser has no knowledge of that and the same security restrictions apply. So yes you're probably better off with a desktop app